# Is there a way in selenium python webdriver to assert that all checkboxes are either checked or unchecked?

Tags: python, selenium, checkbox, selenium-webdriver

I'm building a test that checks that status of many checkboxes on a single page.

Is there a way I can use a loop or something similar to assert that they are all either checked or unchecked?  I'm new to python and python webdriver, so I'm not even sure how I would start something like this.

I've seen answers to similar questions using java, but nothing in python.

Thanks for your help.

@Anzel,  Here's the code I'm using:

```
checkboxes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//input[@type="checkbox"]')
[c.is_selected() for c in checkboxes]
[True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
assert all([c.is_selected() for c in checkboxes])
```

And this gets the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 71, in test_test
assert all([c.is_selected() for c in checkboxes])
AssertionError
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use **is_selected()** to test if that element is *selected*. If you use **find_elements_by_xxx()**, then you just need to loop through it and `assert` their results.

Let see a sample:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlcheckboxes.php'
driver.get(url)
checkboxes = driver.find_elements_by_name('sports')

# simply use is_selected() can yield their Selected status
[c.is_selected() for c in checkboxes]
[False, False, False, False, True, False, False, True]
```

---

```
# to assert they are all unchecked, use not any()
assert not any([c.is_selected() for c in checkboxes])


# so to assert they are all checked, just use all()
assert all([c.is_selected() for c in checkboxes])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-661-c6f9ba4afaf2> in <module>()
----> 1 assert all([c.is_selected() for c in checkboxes])

AssertionError:
```

---

#### Updated:

You can simply find all checkboxes by xpath, this usually works:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//input[@type="checkbox"]')
```

BUT this is not a guarantee, you do need to come up with custom solution from time to time.

And this is a list that Webdriver supports to `find` element:

```
[_ for _ in dir(driver) if 'find' in _]
Out[10]: 
['find_element',
 'find_element_by_class_name',
 'find_element_by_css_selector',
 'find_element_by_id',
 'find_element_by_link_text',
 'find_element_by_name',
 'find_element_by_partial_link_text',
 'find_element_by_tag_name',
 'find_element_by_xpath',
 'find_elements',
 'find_elements_by_class_name',
 'find_elements_by_css_selector',
 'find_elements_by_id',
 'find_elements_by_link_text',
 'find_elements_by_name',
 'find_elements_by_partial_link_text',
 'find_elements_by_tag_name',
 'find_elements_by_xpath']
```

Apparently there's no `by_type`, so it gives you an **AttributeError**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Anzel, but each of my checkboxes has a unique name.  I tried checkboxes = driver.find_elements_by_type('checkbox') but that gave an error: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_type'

Comment: @user4476068, I've updated my answer to provide a general solution. But you shouldn't rely on a **ONE rule fits all** approach, someone can easily build a checkbox from just `div` or `svg` elements...

Comment: Thanks for the update.  My script got past the find_elements_by_xpath statement, but as in your example above I got an assertion error at 'assert all([c.is_selected() for c in checkboxes])'.  I've made sure my True/False match up with what's on the screen, so I'm not sure why it's failing.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user4476068, could you please add **updates** on original post and show the code+error message you get? I have to be clear here, and I hope you understand that I'm not trying to give you a *FULL* solution (as in general in SO too), but rather the essential skills/techniques you've missed to accomplish this.

Comment: I totally understand and I really appreciate your help thus far.  I've pretty much had to jump into the frying pan with python webdriver, so I'm really green at this point.  Your comments have been most helpful and appreciated.  I've updated my original question to include the code I'm using and the error it's producing.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user4476068, no worries we've all been through this stage :) looking at the error, this is the desired result isn't it? Do you want Selenium to wait until all checkboxes are selected?

Comment: When I go to that page, there are 9 checkboxes.  I want to assert that the first 2 are checked and that the last 7 are not checked.  I modified the True/False list to reflect that, but maybe that wasn't correct?  Thanks again :)

Comment: @user4476068, assert is use to test a case/condition, if you want to test this specific condition, you can test the `[True, True, ..., False] == [c.is_selected for c in checkboxes]`

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Anzel, but I'm not quite there yet.  The code from your last comment got me past the error I was seeing, but I don't think it's actually doing the check.  I changed the first 'True' to "False' to make sure it would error, but it didn't throw an error.  The True/False should match up to the state of the checkboxes, correct?  That is, if a box is checked, that's 'True'.  If it's not checked, it's 'False'.  Do I have that right?  thanks.

Comment: @user4476068: yes,  `[True, True...False] == [... in checkboxes]` will check all the True/False in position exactly matches. If you need to verify the first 2 are selected and the rest are not, this should be enough to test it. I really don't know what's your code (from the start to end looks like) or how to actually perform the test, or what exactly you want to achieve. But in terms of the question itself, the technique + code I provided should have already satisfied all the areas you need.